# Can not shut down from the ubuntu gear button,

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I recently install ubuntu 14.04. When  the first days everything was fine  but I have a problem now. When I click the shut down button it does not do any thing but suspend and logout buttons work well. I have installed "Cairo dock" it has shutdown applet. It works well. My system is Dell inspiron 3521 -i3 system with 2GB ram. I really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cario dock screws up the gear if you want it to work again I suggest uninstalling cairo dock.  Or beg them to fix it over here: http://www.glx-dock.org/bg_forumlist.php

Comment: I really love cairo dock. I removed shutdown applet but still shutdown does not work. Should I remove Cairo dock. It's a pain for me. Isn't there another way to fix this

Comment: I'm not sure, mine works, and I have no idea why because it didn't about 2 weeks ago.  Maybe upgrading to 14.10 fixed it I'm not sure, can't really help you there.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I will try your method cause it seems  the only method to solve this,

Comment: Lemme know if it works

Comment: Please mark as resolved if this satisfies you @thanuj

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake. I couldn't log in due to personal matters. I used your method & I have fixed the problem. Thank you very much again,